# XPath xml query : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I did a query to select  all the members aof a xml database file, as you see below:

```
java ApplyXPath wfs.xml /wfs:FeatureCollection/gml:featureMember
```

I got that error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/par
sers/DOMParser
        at ApplyXPath.main(ApplyXPath.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser

        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Yet, i created a Environment CLASSPATH variable as you see below:

```
C:\Users\Johnson\Documents>set CLASSPATH=.;Lab_2/PARTIE_1/exercice_2/xalan.jar;Lab_2/PARTIE_1/exercice_2/xercesImpl.jar;Lab_2/PARTIE_1/exercice_2/xml-apis.jar
```

Here is the beginning of my file wfs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openplans.org/topp http://pigargue.scg.ulaval.ca:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typeName=topp:vueldb http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://pigargue.scg.ulaval.ca:8080/geoserver/data/capabilities/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Box srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32187">
      <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">228433.7636249,5179178.94062699 252694.40491939,5193488.87381481</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Box>
  </gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:featureMember>
    <topp:vueldb fid="vueldb.62444">
      <topp:id_gemure>1582</topp:id_gemure>
      <topp:source>NTDB50</topp:source>
      <topp:id_geom>100</topp:id_geom>
      <topp:type_geom/>
      <topp:type>Road</topp:type>
      <topp:gmiprimary>728</topp:gmiprimary>
      <topp:the_geom>
        <gml:LineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32187">
          <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">247660.63592922,5182347.25435556 247757.95784556,5182226.09265813</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:LineString>
      </topp:the_geom>
    </topp:vueldb>
  </gml:featureMember>
  <gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Could someone explain me what is going wrong?

Thank you.

**Edit**

Here is the code of the ApplyXPath java class:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.apache.xml.utils.*;
import org.apache.xerces.parsers.*;
import org.apache.xpath.*;


public class ApplyXPath {

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try{
      String filename = args[0];
      String xpath = args[1];

      InputSource in = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(filename));
      DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
      parser.parse(in);
      Node root = parser.getDocument().getDocumentElement();
      NodeList nl = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(root,xpath);
      System.out.println("NB ITEM=" + nl.getLength());


      for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength();i++)
    {
      Node item = nl.item(i);
      if(item.getNodeValue() != null)
        System.out.println("Element: Nom= " + item.getNodeName() + " et valeur= " + item.getNodeValue());
else
        System.out.println("Element: Nom= " + item.getNodeName());
    }
   }
    catch(Exception e)
      {
    System.err.println("Il y a un probleme => " + e);
    return;
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: The classpath is probably wrong. Check it very carefully. Perhaps change to absolute paths. Also you are using forward `/`'s in Windows rather than `\`'s. I am not on windows now to quickly check it here, but there are some places in Windows where /'s don't work.

Comment: Also, get an IDE. Or use maven. Or both. It isn't the stone age, we don't have to write classpaths by hand.

Comment: I edited my question and added  the java 'ApplyXPath class' codes.
I changed to absolute paths as follows:
`C:\Users\Johnson\Documents>set CLASSPATH=.;C:/Users/Johnson/Documents/Lab_2/PART
IE_1/exercice_2/xalan.jar;C:/Users/Johnson/Documents/Lab_2/PARTIE_1/exercice_2/x
ercesImpl.jar;C:/Users/Johnson/Documents/Lab_2/PARTIE_1/exercice_2/xml-apis.jar`

After this change i got that result:

`C:\Users\Johnson\Documents\Lab_2\PARTIE_1\exercice_2>java ApplyXPath wfs.xml wfs:featureCollection/gml:featureMember
NB ITEM=0`

Comment: It is definitely a problem with your class path, but without access to the full layout of your filestore we can't know what the problem is. I would always use absolute paths rather than relative paths in a class path variable.